# How can I remove some rows of a 2 dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I remove some rows of a 2 dimensional numpy array? I would like to remove these rows which are cycle or reverse of other row.
Example:

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[4,3,2,1],[1,3,4,2],[2,3,4,5]])
```

the answer is ;

```
answer = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,3,4,2],[2,3,4,5]])
```

Comment: Your values are not duplicate. One is `[2,3,4,1]` other is `[2,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy, and do something like:

```
import numpy as np

test_list = [[1, 0, -1], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 1]]

print("The original list : " + str(test_list))

res = np.unique(np.array([np.sort(sub) for sub in test_list]), axis=0)
 
print("The list after duplicate removal : " + str(res.tolist()))
```

Credits to [Geeks4geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-duplicates-from-nested-list/)

Comment: I reedit my question . last one is unclear. please read again, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicate rows from a 2-dimensional NumPy array, you can use the numpy.unique() function with the axis parameter set to 0. Here's how you can do it with your example array:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5]])

# Use numpy.unique() with axis=0 to remove duplicate rows unique_data = np.unique(data, axis=0)

print(unique_data)
```

Comment: I know np.unique(data,axis=0), Its answer  is not my answer.
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[4,3,2,1],[2,3,4,5]])
>>> np.unique(a,axis=0) 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 1],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [4, 3, 2, 1]])